# How do I get an image from class Account, and use it in PostListView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I got the images working on my template, but the image being displayed is the current logged in user's image.

How do I filter it so that Profile.objects.get(user=[the owner of the post's user])?

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_post'] = Post.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        # context['user_profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id)
        context['user_profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=1)

        return context
```

The error code says: `'PostListView' object has no attribute 'user'`. I don't understand this error code because from my understand `PostListView`'s model is set to `Post` which has the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    ...
```

So in other words every post made to the blog has a user.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_post'] = Post.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    # context['user_profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id)
    context['user_profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=1)

    return context
```

What I believe `self` is doing here is represents the current object in PostListView right?

Can you please ELI5? I am having some trouble understanding the documentation since the language used in there is difficult for me.

Comment: are you using user__id ?  (double underscore) ? You should use double underscore to access the id of user or just use Post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

Comment: @MohitHarshan That would filter and only show posts from that user, but I want their profile photo too to be displayed next to their name in listview.

Comment: If you want to display every post and show their author's image along with then why you are using filter `Post.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)` you can call it as `Post.objects.all()`. In your case you are only trying to call post from a specific user only.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi Post and Profile are from two different classes, if I do `Post.objects.all()` will it have access to Profile class since it is connected via `user`? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
class PostListView(ListView):
   template_name = 'add_template_name.html'
   model = Post
   context_object_name = 'all_posts'

   def get_queryset(self):
       return Post.objects.all()
```

Now in your template add this,

```
{% for post in all_posts %}

   <img src="{{ post.user.profile_picture }}" alt="image">

   <p> {{ post.title }} </p>

{% endfor %}
```

Whenever you want to use foreign key element, in this case user, you can choose `post.user.` Assuming your user model has profile_picture and username, you can display them as `post.user.profile_picture` and `post.user.username` respectively. For more info, you can go through Django docs.